# How to export Python 3.4 input information to JSON?

Tags: python, json, save

I am trying to build an artificial intelligence program that will keep track of information and other stuff, but am having issues with trying to get it to export the information to a a file. I am new to Python and would like some help identifying what could be the issue.

Here is the source code.

```
#Importations
import jsonpickle
import math
import os
import sys
import time
from random import randrange, uniform
#Setups
SAVEGAME_FILENAME = 'aisetup.json'
game_state = dict()
#Program AI
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, creator):
        self.name = name
        self.creator = creator
#User Information
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self, name, birth):
        self.name = name
        self.birth = birth       
#Load Program Save
def load_game():
    """Load game state from a predefined savegame location and return the
    game state contained in that savegame.
    """
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'r') as savegame:
        state = jsonpickle.decode(savegame.read())
    return state
#Save Program to JSON
def save_game():
    """Save the current game state to a savegame in a predefined location.
    """
    global game_state
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'w') as savegame:
        savegame.write(jsonpickle.encode(game_state))
#Initialize Program
def initialize_game():
    """Runs if no AISave is found"""
    UserProg = Human('User', '0/0/0')
    AISystem = Computer('TempAI', 'Austin Hargis')

    state = dict()
    state['UserProg'] = [UserProg]
    state['AISystem'] = [AISystem]
    return state
#TextPad
#Main Code - Runs Multiple Times per Being Openned
def prog_loop():
    global game_state
    name = input (str("What is your name?: "))
    save_game()

#Main Program
def main():
    """Main function. Check if a savegame exists, and if so, load it. Otherwise
    initialize the game state with defaults. Finally, start the game.
    """
    global game_state

    if not os.path.isfile(SAVEGAME_FILENAME):
        game_state = initialize_game()
    else:
        game_state = load_game()
    prog_loop()
#Launch Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Every time I run this, it exports the information to a file like this:

```
{"UserProg": [{"birth": "0/0/0", "py/object": "__main__.Human", "name": "User"}], "AISystem": [{"py/object": "__main__.Computer", "name": "TempAI", "creator": "Austin Hargis"}]}
```

I want it to export your name to the folder but it does not work right.

Answer (score 0):

You never *do* anything with the name the user enters:

```
def prog_loop():
    global game_state
    name = input (str("What is your name?: "))
    save_game()
```

`name` is just a local variable there. If you wanted to save that as the name for the human, then you need to set that on the `UserProg` entry in your game state:

```
def prog_loop():
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    # game_state['UserProg'] is a list with one Human instance in it
    game_state['UserProg'][0].name = name
    save_game()
```

Because you are altering the mutable object contained *in* `game_state` rather than assign to `game_state` itself, you don't need the `global` statement there. The `str()` call was also redundant, the `"..."` syntax already produced a string, there is little point in converting that to a string *again*.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought I was along the right track with this. I had something somewhat like this before but it hadn't worked so I got rid of it.

Comment: How would I use this information again? Like the name, when the program starts, I want it to say "Welcome back (name)". How would I use the name again?

Comment: @AustinHargis: after loading you can access `game_state['UserProg'][0].name` again.

Comment: I tried using that but I am not sure how to use it and where. Like after I close the program and reopen it how would I apply it to use the name again? It currently tells me that name is undefined.

Comment: Right after your `game_state = load_game()` line the game state is loaded and `game_state['UserProg'][0].name` should be available.